# Layout in Android?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I got an error `error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` when i did not add an attribute `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` for my Layout. **Why we want to set this attribute for a layout?Any Specific Reasons?** what i put the [url mentioned](http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android) as a value for `xmlns:android`. I got the server not found Exception. Please Share your knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an attribute for your layout but the namespace for the XML. Adding this xmlns:android would allow you to use all the "android:..." attributes and others.

WRT the 'server not found' exception, can you post the XML file ?

Answer (score 1):

Matthieu explained why you need that attribute.

The reason you're getting a server not found error, is because XML namespace URLs aren't required to actually exist, and in this case they clearly don't.

Comment: Oooh... you mean you were trying to go to that URL with a web browser... sorry, I did not think about that, that makes sense why you would have that error...